# MongoDb driver; "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"

Tags: amazon-web-services, mongodb-.net-driver, aws-documentdb

trying to access recently created documentdb Database in AWS via Code below;

```
    public GetEntities()
    {
        
        _client = new MongoClient("mongodb://username:password@mynode.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false");

        _database = _client.GetDatabase("testdb");
        _collection = _database.GetCollection<UserObject>("testcollection");
    }

    public bool Handle(GetDocumentsQuery message)
    {
        try
        {
            _collection.InsertOne(message);
            var asd = _collection.Find(f => f.Name != "asd").ToList();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

throws this exception:

> ex {"A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using
> CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
> LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
> }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is {
> ClusterId : "1", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected",
> Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint :
> "Unspecified/mydocdbname.amazonaws.com:27017" }", EndPoint:
> "Unspecified/mydocdbname.amazonaws.com:27017", ReasonChanged:
> "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: ,
> TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
> "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> opening a connection to the server. --->
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
> certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.\r\n   at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
> lazyResult)\r\n   at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult
> result)\r\n   at
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)\r\n   at
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
> requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous
> location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__51.MoveNext()\r\n
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__51.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__33.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n
> at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__35.MoveNext()",
> LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2022-07-05T18:31:52.4889181Z",
> LastUpdateTimestamp: "2022-07-05T18:31:52.4889181Z" }] }."}
> System.Exception {System.TimeoutException}

whats missing here?

Comment: you should provide the whole error message

Comment: @dododo I dont know why you need all exception details, provided

Comment: because this is the main reason why server selecting fails: `System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`, something wrong with certificates you use

Comment: @dododo yep, can you aid to resolve this?

Comment: only configure correct certificates :) It's not about programming, but about env setup

Comment: @dododo Do you mean I should resolve this in aws panel not by code? 
Cuz it means its not my responsibility but devops guy, but I need to be sure, isnt it my part? I mean nothing with code here?

Comment: oh, actually no, it's about "code". This option `ssl_ca_certs` is not supported by .net driver. .net mostly requires configuring CA certificates on OS level. For windows it should be done via something like this `certutil.exe -addstore "Root" {cert_name}`

Comment: @dododo yes its windows and when I run command above I encounter this "Cannot add a non-root certificate to the root store", I got cert file from this link: https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

Comment: If I recall correctly, a certificate should be in `pkcs12` format, you can convert it via: `openssl pkcs12 -export -in "${CLIENT_PEM}"  -out "${X509_CLIENT_P12}"   -name "Client Certificate"  -password "pass:${X509_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD}"`

Answer (score 0):

The answer on your question is that .net driver doesn't support `ssl_ca_certs` connection string option, you should configure CA certificate on OS level